# Extend configuration and operational data contexts of Identity Server 4

Tags: entity-framework-core, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I want to customize the configuration and operational data contexts of Identity Server 4 .

I let you see the code just for the configuration store, because the code is really similar.

Here my custom store:

```
internal class MyConfigurationDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
{
    public MyConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
        : base(options, storeOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("configuration");
    }
}
```

Here I have the first doubt. I think the signature of the constructor should be

```
public MyConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
```

but in this case it cannot convert `DbContextOptions<MyConfigurationDbContext>` in `DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>`

Well, in  my sturtup I have this code:

```
builder.AddConfigurationStore<MyConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(MIGRATION_ASSEMBLY));
});
```

Then, I try to generate first migration:

```
Add-Migration InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -Context MyConfigurationDbContext -OutputDir Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
```

But in this case, I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.ConfigurationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'My.IdentityServer.DataLayer.Repository.Contexts.MyConfigurationDbContext'.
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly guessed, you have to use `DbContextOptions<MyConfigurationDbContext>` type for options argument in your context constructor.

But in order to be able to call the base constructor, instead of the default non generic [`ConfigurationDbContext`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/DbContexts/ConfigurationDbContext.cs#L19) you should inherit your context from the generic [`ConfigurationDbContext<TContext>`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/DbContexts/ConfigurationDbContext.cs#L38) using your context type as a generic type argument:

```cs
internal class MyConfigurationDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext<MyConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public MyConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
        : base(options, storeOptions)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What stupid I have been... I had not thought I could change the inheritance of my custom context... It works